# Do you have to reinstall modules for different projects, while using virtualenv?

Tags: python, installation, virtualenv

In python, let's say I have two projects, A and B.  Let's say both projects use numpy, and pandas, but B additionally uses pygame.  If I were to use virtualenv for this, would I create an environment for each, and install numpy and pandas in each (twice)?  If so, wouldn't this waste a lot of time?  Especially for large modules such as numpy, pandas, and matplotlib?

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, installing Numpy and Pandas twice is peanuts. But for two related projects, sharing a single virtualenv might make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is imho like this.
You can always use

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

to batch install the modules.

Comment: That doesn't attempt to address the OP's question.